# Отфильтровать массив от null с помощью arraycopy

Tags: java, массивы, фильтрация

Необходимо отфильтровать массив от `null` с помощью `arraycopy`. Пытаюсь совместить перебор и `arraycopy`, нашли `null` - двигаем ровно на один элемент влево. При использовании такой конструкции пропадают `null` между элементами, но те что в конце нет и выпадает `NullPointerException`. `arraycopy` использовать обязательно.

```java
public Service[] getServices() {
    for (int i = 0; services.length > i; i++) {
        if (services[i] == null) {
            System.arraycopy(services, i+1, services, i, services.length - i -1);
        }
    }
    return services;
}
```

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит изменять массив, с которым вы в данный момент работаете в цикле `for`. Лучше вместо этого использовать рекурсию:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] arr1 = new Object[]{null, "9", 1, null, "noll", null};
    Object[] arr2 = removeNulls(arr1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [null, 9, 1, null, noll, null]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [9, 1, noll]
}
```

```java
public static Object[] removeNulls(Object[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == null) {
            Object[] newArr = new Object[arr.length - 1];
            if (i > 0) {
                System.arraycopy(arr, 0, newArr, 0, i);
            }
            System.arraycopy(arr, i + 1, newArr, i, arr.length - i - 1);
            arr = removeNulls(newArr);
            break;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

---

На стримах это можно сделать в одну строчку:

```java
public static Object[] removeNulls(Object[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray();
}
```